# How to pass component props to Emotion styles

Tags: css, reactjs, emotion

I was struggling with this so I'm gonna put this here in case anyone else needs it:

**Button.js**

```
import styles from './Button.styles'

function Button(props) {
    return (
        <button css={styles.button(props)} {...props}>
            {props.label}
        </button>
    )
}
```

**Button.styles.js**

```
export default {
    button: (props) => (theme) => {
        const { colors } = theme

        return {
            color: colors.pureWhite,
            backgroundColor:
                (props.primary && colors.primaryBlue) ||
                (props.critical && colors.red)
        }
    }
}
```